# How do I calculate a bounding polygon?

Tags: geometry, polygon, points

I have a cloud of 2D points and I would like to calculate the perimeter of a polygon which encompasses all of them.

Is there a name for this mathematical process which I can Google or can someone tell me how to start thinking about the problem, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) and for [convex hull algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms).

One of the simplest 2D algorithms is the [Gift wrapping algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm). To quote Wikipedia:

> It has O(*nh*) time complexity, where *n* is the number of points and *h* is the number of points on the convex hull. Its real-life performance compared with other convex hull algorithms is favorable when *n* is small or *h* is expected to be very small with respect to *n*. In general cases the algorithm is outperformed by many others.

So depending on the size of your problem, you might need to take a look on the algorithms page linked above in order to find more advanced approaches.

Comment: Thank you. One little extension to this question: What if the hull needs to shrink-wrap a little (or a lot)? I have a cloud of points which represent a blob of water, so some are a valid indent in the side of the hull.

Comment: Just an thought, but if you use something similar to the gift wrapping algorithm but added a constraint that the next point in the hull must be within a certain distance of a given point you may be able to get your so-called "shink-wrap" effect. I'm not sure how the point cloud is computed but you would have to have some sort of guarantee that a point exists in this distance.

Answer (score 2):

One well-defined such polygon is the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). There are several well-studied [algorithms for finding convex hulls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms).